# What is the name of such a chord or what type of chord is it?

Tags: chords, chord-progressions, electronic-music

This is a simple progression of chords, but if the first two chords are just "Bbm", "Ab", they have names, no problem, but then what are the last two? How can I interpret them?

Context: progression of chords on which a musical composition is built;

[image]

Comment: With a Bbm chord quoted as having A# and C#, I'd move on to a site where they actually knew what they were talking about!

Comment: Fix the enharmonic spelling errors first, then analyze it including identifying melody and non-chord tones from harmonic tones, then if you still have a question about a chord identity or harmonic function, post that specific question. Otherwise your question amounts to "teach me harmony."

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Thanks for your comment, what terms and definitions should i google to answer my question?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis maybe youtube channels or books or another useful stuff

Comment: This is a pretty good starting resource: https://www.musictheory.net/lessons

Comment: @AndyBonner Thanks ☀️

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

1. **"Enharmonic spelling" matters.** "Enharmonic," meaning two different names for the same piano key, like how C# and Db are the same. A Bbm chord is spelled "Bb Db F." Yes, the Bb is the same piano key as A# and Db is same as C#, but if we want a Bbm chord, we'd choose the spelling with the flats. The general idea is that the notes of a simple ("triadic") chord in root position should "look like a snowman" in staff notation: You skip a letter in between each note: "Bb (skip C) Db (skip E) F."

   A. Why does this matter? If enharmonic notes are the same, who cares what name we use? Because as soon as we start naming chords, we move into *subjective* analysis. An objective description of this passage would just be that certain keys were pressed together. Once we start naming the chords, we're saying something about what they mean all together in context.
2. **"Voicing" doesn't matter** to identifying a chord. A C chord contains C, E, and G, but any one of them can be on the bottom. And you could have more than one E, or even leave the E out. (In that case, people would *guess* that it's a C major chord from context.) So, for example, the last chord contains two D#s; that doesn't matter. I'd rename the pitches shown to Eb, Ab, and C, then find "root position" by imagining the notes on the staff and rearranging them to form a "snowman" and discover that that happens when Ab is on the bottom; it's an Ab major chord, just like the second chord.
3. **Sometimes you have to guess**, based on context. The third chord is the weird thing here. It's unlikely to have both an F and an F#; let's rename that F# to Gb (and C# to Db). If we plot these on the staff, there's no way to make a snowman. I think there's an "implied" note left out. If there were a Bb, we could make a 4-note "snowman" with Gb, Bb, Db, F: a seventh chord, G flat major 7th.

So what about the context led me to that guess? First, look at the bass notes. They walk down in steps at first: Bb, Ab, Gb. In fact, the second chord just takes all the notes of the first chord and lowers them. (The middle note moves only a half step, while the outer notes move a whole step, just because that's how the notes in the key of Bb go.) If the pattern continued, the next chord would be Gb. But the pianist decides to let the right hand follow an oscillating pattern: (Db F), (C Eb), and then repeats (Db F), (C Eb). Combined with the motion of the left hand, we "fill in" the missing Bb of the third chord in our imagination.

Comment: I reckon you could leave out the G, but not the E, to guess that it's a C  major chord. Which, I'm guessing, is what you meant! (2). Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think voicing doesn't matter. E.g., if you put 9, or 6 or 13 in the bass voice that will likely change the identity of the chord.

Comment: @user1079505 - I guess Andy's talking about basic triads, or at most 4 note chords, where, in fact, voicing doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Tim yes, I understand it, but one needs to be careful when formulating general conclusions from simple examples.

Comment: @user1079505 I *somewhat* agree with you—and somewhat stand by my position. I'm thinking of a classical rather than jazz context. In classical, the composer just puts dots on the page and it's up to the theorist to decide what to call them. In jazz, the composer often puts *chords names* on the page, and the performer constructs them. The flow is reversed! But as long as we are performing analysis rather than composing, we're deciding what chord name to assign a given bunch of dots, and sure, the note in the bass is a pretty good clue, but overall harmonic context is even more important. ...

Comment: ... This kind of plays into @Tim's first question, too: it's all about context. If I play Twinkle Twinkle Little Star in C and end with no third in my final C chord... well sure, it *could* be minor... but it's very unlikely. And the listener will probably "hear" major.